# Customization of JDev Code Editor

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

I have a small problem in customizing JDeveloper's Code Editor. I want to be able to change the position of the Grey line that is used by the IDE to wrap my java code. See image below.

[image: example]

I looked inside preferences>Code Editor options and everywhere around but found no option that could change it. And btw, what is this grey line called?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find this option under 'Tools->Preferences->Code Editor->Display' and it's called 'Right Margin Column'. It's used when you format the code as the point where a line should break.

Comment: When i `Reformat` my code, it will still wrap text. I want to wrap text only when it reaches the right margin. Not before. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Ah, I forgot this... This option is hidden in the code style section unter 'tools->preferences->code editor' then hit the edit button and open the node 'Line Wrapping' there you find the 'Lone width'option. Set this to the the value of the 'Right Margin Column' and it should work.